# Is in c++11 something similar for threads to node.js/javascript callbacks?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I start a [thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) from the main thread, is there any option to hook callback which the new thread is going to trigger. Callback should be executed in the main thread.

At the moment I am using [future](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/) for this task but I want to avoid waiting for result (result is boolean, in case `true` everything is ok, in case `false` I need to start again thread to try to do task).
Is in c++11 something similar to node.js/javascript callbacks?

Comment: @texasbruce I am using async with future, but when you want to see result you need to wait until that thread finishes. I need something like signal or event, to avoid waiting

Comment: Why not just start from a spawned thread?

Comment: i dont really understand what u wanna do, but what about: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing explicitly for doing this in *current standard* C++.

`std::future::then()` is in the standardization pipeline and may be included in C++1y or a TR.

There are several third-party libraries which support this idiom:

- [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then)
- Intel [Threading Building Blocks (TBB)](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)
- [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/)
- Microsoft [Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750113.aspx) [Windows only]
- Microsoft [Casablanca](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/)

Related: [Asio](http://think-async.com/) is a C++ asynchronous I/O library that supports this idiom just for non-blocking I/O operations, not general computation operations. (Node.js is mainly used for I/O, so this might be adequate.)

Otherwise, you can roll your own workaround:

```
auto myFuture = std::async([](){
    doWork();
}).share();
auto myNextFuture = std::async([=](){
    myFuture.wait();
    doMoreWork();
});
```

You can package this up into a reusable helper:

```
template <typename Future, typename Work>
auto after(Future f, Work w) -> std::future<decltype(w())>
{
    return std::async([=]() -> decltype(w()) { f.wait(); return w(); });
}
```

And use it like so:

```
auto myFuture = std::async([](){
    doWork();
});
auto myNextFuture = after(myFuture.share(), [](){
    doMoreWork();
});
```

With this approach you pay for the cost of an extra thread (probably).

Related: [C++ Concurrency](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) talk by Herb Sutter.

Comment: Remember to set the `std::launch::deferred` or `std::launch::async`, so that you have total control over the scheduling. You should use `async`, I believe. It's not as efficient as `then()` because it creates an additional thread (system resource) that blocks constantly, and after it unblocks it will potentially incur a processor switch, loosing the hot cache.

Answer (score 2):

std::future::then() and the continuation implementations listet by Oktalist will do a good job, if you do not really need to execute the callback in the main thread. But if it is a requirement they will not be enough.

If you have an event loop running ( most GUI applications will have one ) you could notify the loop from the continuation to execute your callback.

In Qt you could send a signal from inside the continuation to an object living in the main thread. The event loop will eventually execute the slot in the main thread.

If you do not have an event loop boost coroutines may be an option, but I have not used them myself.

Answer (score 1):

Make a queue of tasks to run in the main thread.  Set it up to be many-writer one-reader thread safe (there are many imlementations of this, in CS texts or on the web).

The queue should fire a signal when it is non-empty, and allow the reader to wait on it.

Have your thread enqueue a task in this queue.  Make the main thead wait on it.

If the main thread has to do other things 'meanwhile', enqueue those tasks in the same thread.  Ie, if you respond to user input, have the user input reading thread toss tasks onto that queue representing user input to be processed.

For reaponsiveness reasons, the thread processing user input should avoid complex calculations.

This technique is called a 'message pump' -- the 'main' thread serves the message pump (the queue of tasks), handlimg each message (enqueued task) in order.  In industrial scale applications abstract requests are sent rather than explicit tasks each time, and meta processing of messages (fallback handlers etc) occurs.

Your 'run on main thread' consists of enqueing a message for the main thread that says 'run this task'.

A 'traditional' C++ program's main thread is not a message pump, so injecting code to run is infeasible.  Most gui frameworks have a message pump system uou can hook into.  As javascript is a ui-centric language, the main thead is implicitly serving something like a message pump.